# How to modify this color?

Tags: css

I would like to find the color / the code of the borders (the green thing) of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psCbg.png), to replace it by red (#ff0000).

I don't know how and I'm searching since like 1 hour and I start to be bored, sorry . Of this borders, and this text :

Here is my CSS : https://hastebin.com/royatezigu.css

Thanks for help.

Edit: look my comment for code

Comment: My code (html) : https://hastebin.com/yoweyevuse.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this :

```
div.block,div.infoblock{
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px 1px #23CA20;
box-shadow:0 0 4px 1px #23CA20;
margin-bottom:1.69em
}
```

change `#23CA20` to your desired color.

Additional Information:

You can always use Developer tools on browsers like Chrome and firefox, to check on any page's CSS.

Comment: It's working good thank you. But do you know a website or something to "format" (I don't know the exact work since I'm French sorry) my CSS, because actually it's on only 1 line so it's hard to "read". Thanks.

Comment: Single-Line CSS = "compressed" CSS. I don't recall any website to reformat the CSS structure other than doing it manually by Search & Replace (that's how I do it) on any editor that supports multiple lines in search.

Answer (score 0):

did you search it by "border-color" tag ?. i found ( #4a831c and #23CA20 ) color codes. just check.

Comment: Yeah but it was not that. Look @iSR5 answer.

Comment: ctrl + f and find the color code by using that tag. and just replace the color what you want and try.